# Local php.ini Why default timezone is different from Main php.ini

Tags: php, linux, timezone

On server,

```
$date
Wed Jan 20 13:28:04 PST 2016
```

On main `php.ini`,

The default timezone is set to `America/Los_Angeles`.

I could confirm that by if I removed local `php.ini` and print `phpinfo()`.

However, when local  `php.ini` exists, regardless the file does not have configurations to change default timezone, default timezone will be changed to `UTC`. It generates this error

```
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. 
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, 
you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
```

I understand `date_default_timezone_set()` could make this error resolved.

However, I want to know what is the issue, why is not loading the default timezone correctly. Because I do not want to put this function to scripts.....

Thank your advise!!